# R: asynchronous parallel lapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, lapply, furrr

The simplest way I've found so far to use a parallel `lapply` in R was through the following example code:

```
library(parallel)
library(pbapply)

cl <- makeCluster(10)
clusterExport(cl = cl, {...})
clusterEvalQ(cl = cl, {...})

results <- pblapply(1:100, FUN = function(x){rnorm(x)}, cl = cl)
```

This has a very useful feature of providing a progress bar for the results, and is very easy to reuse the same code when no parallel computations are needed, by setting `cl = NULL`.

However, one issue that I've noted is that the `pblapply` is looping through the list in batches. For example, if one worker is stuck for a long time on a certain task, the remaining workers will wait for it to finish before starting a new batch of jobs. For certain tasks this adds a lot of unnecessary time to the workflow.

**My question:**
Are there any similar parallel frameworks that would allow for the workers to run independently? Progress bar and the ability to reuse the code with `cl=NULL` would be a big plus.

Maybe it is possible to modify the existing code of `pbapply` to add this option/feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of the [**future**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future) framework and the [**progressr**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/progressr) package)

A close solution that resembles `base::lapply()`, and your `pbapply::pblapply()` example, is to use the [**future.apply**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future.apply) as:

```
library(future.apply)

## The below is same as plan(multisession, workers=4)
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(4)
plan(cluster, workers=cl)

xs <- 1:100
results <- future_lapply(xs, FUN=function(x) {
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  sqrt(x)
})
```

**Chunking**:
You can control the amount of chunking with argument `future.chunk.size` or supplementary `future.schedule`.  To disable chunking such that each element is processed in a unique parallel task, use `future.chunk.size=1`.  This way, if there is one element that takes much longer than other elements, it will not hold up any other elements.

```
xs <- 1:100
results <- future_lapply(xs, FUN=function(x) {
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  sqrt(x)
}, future.chunk.size=1)
```

**Progress updates in parallel:**
If you want to receive progress updates when doing parallel processing, you can use [**progressr**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/progressr) package and configure it to use the [**progress**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/progress) package to report updates as a progress bar (here also with an ETA).

```
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession, workers=4)

library(progressr)
handlers(handler_progress(format="[:bar] :percent :eta :message"))

with_progress({
  p <- progressor(along=xs)
  results <- future_lapply(xs, FUN=function(x) {
    p()  ## signal progress
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    sqrt(x)
  }, future.chunk.size=1)
})
```

You can wrap this into a function, e.g.

```
my_fcn <- function(xs) {
  p <- progressor(along=xs)
  future_lapply(xs, FUN=function(x) {
    p()
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    sqrt(x)
  }, future.chunk.size=1)
}
```

This way you can call it as a regular function:

```
> result <- my_fcn(xs)
```

and use `plan()` to control exactly how you want it to parallelize.  This will not report on progress.  To do that, you'll have to do:

```
> with_progress(result <- my_fcn(xs))
[====>-----------------------------------------------------]   9%  1m
```

**Run everything in the background:** If your question was how to run the whole shebang in the background, see the '[Future Topologies](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-3-topologies.html)' vignette.  That's another level of parallelization but it's possible.

Comment: This is awesome! All the controls that I was looking for. Great job with the framework! Still, for some reason, I'm not seeing the progress bar printed, must be something with my machine...

Comment: The progress bar prints without problems on the linux machine though, but not on windows + microsoft R 3.5.1.  Is this a known issue?

Comment: "The progress bar prints without problems ... but not on windows + microsoft R 3.5.1 ...": @Nutle, are you referring to the **progressr** solution in my answer, or some other solution mention in this post?  If my example code in the above answer, which uses **progressr**, does _not_ please let me know.

Comment: Yes, the progressr solution. Maybe some version mismatch (or other loaded packages?) - had to install from github, since the CRAN/MRAN version wasn't available for 3.5.1. I can also confirm that R 4.0.2 works too on the same windows machine, so only the Microsoft R seems to be affected.

Comment: Oh, yeah you need future (>= 1.16.0) [2020-01-15] for near-live updates to work, so maybe that was the problem.

Comment: That will be the case, I'm working with a 2018-08 MRAN snapshot, where 1.9 was the latest. All updated now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`furrr`](https://github.com/DavisVaughan/furrr) package which uses [`future`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-1-overview.html) to run [`purrr`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) in multiprocess mode :

```
library(furrr)
plan(multisession, workers = nbrOfWorkers()-1)
nbrOfWorkers()
1:100 %>% future_map(~{Sys.sleep(1); rnorm(.x)},.progress = T)
Progress: ──────────────────────────────                                   100%
```

You can switch off parallel computations with `plan(sequential)`

Comment: Thanks, the package looks promising. Any way to control the number of workers and functions/data passed to them with ``plan(multisession)``? Plus, the progress bar for some reason is not showing on my session, will have to investigate why.

Comment: see my edit : the progress bar disappears after completion, I slowed this down. You can also set #workers

Comment: Very good. To see the "time remaining" would also be useful, but this will have to do. Going to do some more testing and accept your answer eventually. Thanks!